# "Ältere Schwester" oder "große Schwester"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I have two older sisters. How can I say these two words below in German?

> 1. my oldest sister
> 2. my older sister (another sister)

Comment: Was hat die Frage mit der in der Überschrift erwähnten großen Schwester zu tun?

Answer (score 5):

Principally for an older sister you have the options

> (1) meine ältere Schwester
>
> (2) meine große Schwester

Choosing from these two is a question of style and context. (1) is more appropriate in formal contexts, (2) would typcially be used in communication with friends and family.

Now, if you want to differentiate between two older sisters, things get a little bit more complicated.

Here are sentences in well-formed everyday language:

> Ich habe zwei ältere Schwestern. Die eine heißt Maria, und die andere heißt Franziska. Maria ist die ältere/größere, Franziska ist die jüngere/kleinere.
>
> Ich habe vier Schwestern, zwei sind älter als ich,  zwei sind jünger als ich. Die älteste Schwester heißt Maria, die zweitälteste Franziska, die jüngste heißt Ute, und die zweitjüngste heißt Dorothee. Ich bin das mittlere Kind und heiße Dieter.
>
> Die jüngere meiner beiden älteren Schwestern heißt Maria, die ältere heißt Franziska. Die älteste [oder: ältere] meiner beiden jüngeren Schwestern heißt Dorothee.

The third example is a little bit awkward because of "die ältere der älteren Schwestern" - there is too much of the same word "ältere" in slightly different meanings. But I do not see a really good, elegant way out here.

Comment: Große und größere, wie kleine und kleinere passt nur, solange es sich um Kinder handelt. Zur Adoleszenz hin und ab da können die jüngeren durchaus größer werden als die älteren, was eine Substitution des einen Wortes durch ein anderes durchkreuzt. Selbst wenn die Größe dem Alter entspricht kann es der Hörer ja nicht wissen.

Comment: Das ist zwar von der Logik her richtig, in der Sprachpraxis des Alltags jedoch irrelevant. Das Wort *groß* wird in diesem Zusammenhang nie im Sinne von Körpergröße verstanden sondern steht praktisch immer für das Alter. - Ich stimme jedoch zu, dass Personen jenseits der Jugendgrenze kaum mehr von "meine große Schwester" sprechen sondern eher "meine ältere Schwester" sagen. (Wenn sie die Reihenfolge überhaupt erwähnen, denn wann ist das schon von Bedeutung im Erwachsenenalter. Da sagt man in aller Regel einfach "meine Schwester".)

Comment: Das bestreite ich. Wenn man zwei Schwestern hat, von denen die eine signifikant größer ist, ohne älter zu sein, kann man durchaus "große" benutzen.

Comment: Vielen Dank :)  sehr gute Erklärung!  Deutsche Grammatik ist richtig schwer aber interessant!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. meine älteste Schwester
> 2. meine nächstältere Schwester

*»nächstälter«* is a constructed term which is not part of the dictionary. It's similar to [*»nächsthöher«*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/naechsthoeher).

Comment: "Nächstältere" setzt aber vorraus, dass Du zuvor von der ältesten gesprochen hast. Wieso nicht "zweitälteste"?

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn zunächst nicht von Schwestern gesprochen wird und ich beginne mit _»Meine nächstältere Schwester«_, dann kann man das nur so verstehen, dass diejenige meiner älteren Schwestern gemeint ist, die meinem eigenen Alter am nächsten kommt.

Comment: Ich verstehe:) Dankeschön!!

Comment: @Pollitzer: Das bestreite ich. Wenn zuvor von Dir und Deinem Alter die Rede war, vielleicht. Allerdings kann man streiten, ob, wenn Du 12 bist und Schwestern im Alter von 11, 14 und 17 hast, die 14jährige gemeint ist, weil sie unter den älteren am nächsten ist, oder die 11jährige, die vom Alter her die nächste ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ich als 12-Jähriger ohne Vorbemerkungen _»Meine nächst**ältere** Schwester«_ sage, wird wohl niemand glauben, ich meine meine **jüngere** Schwester, die 11 ist. Anders, wenn ich zuvor von meinem 9-jährigen Bruder rede.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Vom Alter kommt die älteste jüngere Schwester nach Dir, während die jüngste Ältere vor Dir kommt. Aber gut - die jüngere wäre die nächstälteste nach Dir. Aber wenn Du jetzt 4 ältere Schwestern hast ist die älteste klar. Die nächstälteste ist die 2., die nächstältere die 4.

Answer (score 1):

I am a german native speaker, the direct and simple answer to your question would be:

```
    my oldest sister
    my older sister (another sister)
```

oldest sister --> meine **älteste** Schwester
older sister --> meine **ältere** Schwester

So you can simply call the one in the middle your *ältere* Schwester and the firsTborn your *älteste* Schwester :D

Comment: Das klingt wie Englisch ^^ Dankeschön!

Answer (score 0):

I see no other solution as

> Meine große Schwester

as opposed to

> Meine kleine Schwester

That even your little sister is older than you has to transported elsewhere. The only alternative would be a complicated construct like

> Die jüngere/ältere meiner großen Schwestern